# aspnet zero - replace IPermissionChecker for Test Module

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, aspnetboilerplate

I am creating another test module for an application service which is using different DbContext.

Is there any way to bypass permission checking for the application service in Unit Test?

I've tried

```
Configuration.ReplaceService<IPermissionChecker, NullPermissionChecker>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
```

in Test Module PreInitialize() but it is still checking the permissions.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: try  

IocManager.RegisterIfNot<IPermissionChecker, NullPermissionChecker>(DependencyLifeStyle.Singleton);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`services.AddAbpIdentity` replaces IPermissionChecker again. You can use `AddPermissionChecker<NullPermissionChecker>` extension method after `services.AddAbpIdentity`.

For AspNet Zero, it's inside `IdentityRegistrar` class. Example (add the last line):

```
services.AddAbpIdentity<Tenant, User, Role>(options =>
    {
        ...
    })
    ...
    .AddPermissionChecker<NullPermissionChecker>();
```

Notice that: You probably want to make this conditional and apply only for unit tests.

Comment: Thanks! I've created Configuration for the module to make this conditional.